# string type doesn't work properly unless passed by reference

Tags: c++, stdstring

I faced the problem in a bigger project so I made a test class hoping I can identify and solve it:

```
class test_class{

public:
    int length;
    const char* cstr;

    test_class(){cstr = nullptr; length = 0;}

    void SetStr(string str){cstr = str.c_str(); length = str.length();}

};
```

So when I use the `SetStr` member function, the first character in `cstr` behaves like a null-terminator. The following code is an example:

```
string str5="abcdefg";

    test_class test;
    test.SetStr(str5);

    cout<<test.cstr<<endl;
```

`cout` outputs nothing, but the characters after the first one are valid. So if I print them with a loop, I get the whole string except for the first character.

But if I rewrite the `SetStr` function as follows(adding the `&`):

```
 void SetStr(string& str){cstr = str.c_str(); length = str.length();}
```

It works fine.

**Question:**
I don't understand what is wrong with the function without the `&`, and how does it fix the problem?

Comment: Long story short, when you pass the `string` by value, the `c_str` is only valid until you return from the function, because the copy of the function is destroyed. When you pass by reference, the lifetime of the string exists outside the scope of the function.

Comment: Don't use `char*`, problem solved.

Comment: If you don't pass by reference then your function makes its own copy of the string and destroys it when the function returns. When the copy of the string is destroyed the data your `const char* cstr;` is pointing at gets de-allocated.

Comment: If you are doing this to learn (otherwise you should not be doing this), then you need to allocate memory and use C string functions to copy the string. You also need to `delete[]` the memory when done as well.

Comment: @crashmstr why shouldn't I be doing this? I barely ever use std::string, but I'm in kind of a hurry right now so I thought I should use it instead of writing my own functions. I'm essentially creating a data-type that behaves like a regular string, except that its index starts at 1 and can be referenced directly using `[]` with minimal functionality and modification.

Comment: @Hex4869 You could still simply use `std::string` internally if you only want to offset indices. Let it handle all construction/copy/destruction.

Comment: @Hex4869 While there is nothing wrong with indexing starting with 1, *most languages don't do this*, and it could be confusing. Also, If you want to write "natural" C++, you should be using `std::string` as a default, just like you should prefer `std::vector` and other container classes over raw arrays.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan That was the initial plan, but I'm doing this for a certain assignment. The indexes always start at 1 in the the assignment and refers to the "string" data type as a "character string". Since I can't ask anyone for details on how it should be done if I'm using C++, I thought probably creating my own "character string" type is the best way, but now I forgot why I thought using string as an internal container was a bad idea.

Comment: @crashmstr I used std::vector a few times, but I always felt like std::string wasn't transparent enough so I avoided it. But now I'm a little more familiar with it so I'll probably use it more often in the future.

Comment: `std::string` is just a `std::vector` with the assumption that the contents are character-like, and that it should ensure there is a `'\0'` at the end of the buffer, and that "one sided" `char*` pointers fed to it are null-terminated.  Then there is a bunch of manipulation stuff, and a possibility that it uses the small buffer optimization for short strings (stores them in itself instead of on the free store).  I do not know if SBO is blocked in C++11 (swap semantics and iterators?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference lies in which object owns the data that `cstr` points to.

```
string str5="abcdefg";

test_class test;
test.SetStr(str5);

cout<<test.cstr<<endl;
```

When you pass by reference, `SetStr` retrieves the pointer directly from `str5` - `str5` owns the data and the pointer remains valid for as long as `str5` exists.
Since `str5` still exists when you print `test.cstr`, everything is fine.

When you pass by value, the data is owned by the parameter, which is a copy of `str5`.
Since the parameter object is destroyed when the function returns, the pointer to its data is invalid afterwards, and dereferencing it is undefined.